# Get all data of parent child relation-ship from same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all rows which meets the parent child relation ship.
for example

```
  id         Title    parent_id
  1200        A       1000
  1201        B       1000
  1202        C       1000
  1203        D       1000
  1204        E       1200
  1205        F       1200
  1206        G       1201
  1207        H       1205
  1208        I       1205
  1209        J       1205
```

Now i have 1209 id, I want to retrieve all rows which satisfy parent child relation ship for 1209. Like here 1209 relates to 1205, 1205 relates to 1200, and 1200 relates to 1000.

I tried this query

```
  SELECT * FROM `category` a left join category b on a.id=b.parent_id where a.id=1209
```

But this is giving me only one record. We are trying to get all rows which comes in this relationship.

Comment: MySQL has little support for hierarchal relationships/recursive queries.  You might find this interesting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting topic. But don't have too much time to read this briefly. I will read this later.

Comment: select * from category as child join category as parent on parent.parent_id = child.id 

this query giving me all data but when i am passing id=1209 in it, Then its giving me again one row.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you're just looking for it's parent,grandparent,greatgrand parent you can use something like this.

```
SELECT id,title,parent_id FROM
    (SELECT id,title,parent_id,
       CASE WHEN id = 1209 THEN @id := parent_id
            WHEN id = @id THEN @id := parent_id
            END as checkId
     FROM Test
     ORDER BY id DESC) as T
WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ea0f/26)

And just in case if you wanted to find all children, and grand children or great grand children of an id you can use this

```
SELECT id,title,parent_id FROM
    (SELECT id,title,parent_id,
            CASE WHEN id = 1200 THEN @idlist := CONCAT(id)
                 WHEN FIND_IN_SET(parent_id,@idlist) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist,',',id)
            END as checkId
     FROM Test
     ORDER BY id ASC) as T
WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle for finding children](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ea0f/39)

query for finding all parents/grandparents/greatgrandparents of multiple children

```
SELECT id,title,parent_id FROM
(SELECT id,title,parent_id,
       CASE WHEN id in (1209,1206) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(IFNULL(@idlist,''),',',parent_id)
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET(id,@idlist) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist,',',parent_id)
            END as checkId
FROM Test
ORDER BY id DESC)T
WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ea0f/51)

Comment: Great. Can i use this for nth level?

Comment: yeah try it out as long as your child's ids are always larger than parent's id it should work

Comment: Yes. I think that always greater then parent's id. 
Its working. Thanks. I spent 6 hours on this but failed.

Comment: I added a query for finding all children/grandchildren/greatgrandchildren nth level just in case you needed it.

Comment: Sorry, But i just found bug. I replaced your query with 'IN' clause for id, But its not working correctly. Here is modified query http://pastebin.com/hP5KqWYd

Comment: I have added a third query (bottom of answer) for finding parents/grandparents/greatgrandparents/ for multiple children. try it out and let me know

Comment: Sorry. but not working correctly. You can check my data and result here 
https://postimg.org/image/5swb7dw53/

https://postimg.org/image/3n20cvson/

Comment: Here is the fiddle if you want
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56359/1 You can see menu4 is not showing.

Comment: You didn't use the last query at bottom of answer (3rd query)

Comment: Strange, I copied your query but not working on my phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

**Get other records with same parent_id as the given record**

To get all the returns of other branches for the same company I belong to (identifed by same `parent_id` in the table) I use this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `sale_return` RET
WHERE RET.`fk_contact_id` IN (
    SELECT OTHERS.`contact_id`
    FROM `contact` ME
    INNER JOIN `contact` OTHERS
        ON ME.`parent_id` = OTHERS.`parent_id`
    WHERE ME.`contact_id` = $customer_id
)
```

Hope it could help some of you.