# Parent Child stations in a company hierarchically

Tags: mysql

Hence the parent company should have access to all its children companies' stations, hierarchically. For example, we have 3 companies A, B, and C owning respectively 10, 5, and 2 charging stations. Company B belongs to A and company C belongs to B.
Then we can say that company A owns 17, company B owns 7, and company C owns 2 charging stations in total.

Database

> 1. Station (id, name, company_id, address)
> 2. Company (id, parent_company_id, name)

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL Version 8.0.17

Comment: In your version you can use recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have created query got help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523356/get-all-data-of-parent-child-relation-ship-from-same-table-in-mysql/36523552).

```
SELECT id,name,parent_company_id FROM
    (SELECT id,name,parent_company_id,
            CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN @idlist := CONCAT(id)
                 WHEN FIND_IN_SET(parent_company_id,@idlist) THEN @idlist := CONCAT(@idlist,',',id)
            END as checkId
     FROM Test
     ORDER BY id ASC) as T
WHERE checkId IS NOT NULL
```

It will return all ids and on those ids base i can get stations count.